# Recursively find ".sh" file and then execute my .sh file on that path

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a folder which contains sub sub folders and some folders contains .sh file. I want to execute my .sh file in that path where I see a .sh file. I tried

```
find . -name '*.sh' 
./folder 1/folder 2/run.sh
./folder3/run.sh
./folder 4/run.sh
./folder5/run.sh
```

This find function is working correctly. Now I have another .sh file which I want to execute on .sh file path. I tried

```
find . -name '*.sh' /home/cool/Desktop/followup.sh {} ;
```

where followup.sh is my file. The command is getting executed at current directory . but it is not getting executed on run.sh file path.

I am new to bash scripting. What command or commands would I issue? Note that there are spaces in Folder name.

Comment: Basically you missed the `-exec`: It should be `find . -name '*.sh' -exec /home/cool/Desktop/followup.sh {} \;`

Comment: Besides that, if you want to run the script within the path of that file, use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`: `find . -name '*.sh' -execdir /home/cool/Desktop/followup.sh {} \;`

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks. execdir worked.

Comment: @hek2mgl I tried in another folder of mine and I am getting following error ```chmod: cannot access ‘*.sh’: No such file or directory
/home/cool/Desktop/followup.sh: ./*.sh: not found``` . Any workaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find <parent-directory where all sub-folders with run.sh are located> -name '*.sh' -execdir /home/cool/Desktop/followup.sh {} \;
```

Comment: Does it works if instead of have a file with my job (e.g. /home/cool/Desktop/followup.sh) I have a line command to execute all found .sh?